# Differentiation of modulus %

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic

I am solving a problem 
which states i have n units and two screen to display  namely sc1=0 and sc2=0 
Now, sc1 takes 1 unit to increase by 1  and sc2 takes b units to increase by number on  sc1 ie. if after 5 units  sc1 =5 and  then i take b units from n  now sc2 =5  and if i take again then  then  becomes sc2=10.
Now ,i want to know what is sc2 maximum value when my becomes 0.

I came up  with this expression   `Y`
now maximum value x will give me my answer But i how .
Can i differentiate this expression `Y =x -((n-x)-(n-x)%b ) w.r.t x` where `% returns remainder  and n and b are constants`

Comment: How .Please explain

Comment: Remainder is usually not considered differentiable.

Comment: So i can just assume it to be zero

Comment: Remainder and modulus are not continuous nor differentiable.

Comment: It's not clear what "maximize" means inside a modulus.  If you want to, you can say the maximum comes when $x=-(b-1)+n$, in which case $Y\equiv b-1\pmod b$.  But is that what you meant?

Comment: My full expression is Y =n/2 -((n-x)-(n-x)%b ).     So this implies  dy/dx is max at n/2

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to differentiate inside a modulus.

Comment: So how can this be solved ?

Comment: You may edit the question to give more details..

Comment: I don't think you are listening to the commentators.  What do you mean by maximize?  That's not a standard concept in modular arithmetic.  As I say, if you say the residues are $0<1<2<\cdots<b-1$ then the  theoretical "maximum" occurs if $Y=b-1$ and we can hit that value by taking $x=-(b-1)+n$.  But I doubt that is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modular functions like `Y=(n-x)%b` are not differentiable everywhere.  They have a discontinuity at every multiple of `b`.  They are, however, differentiable everywhere else.  In your case, the derivative, `dY/dx` would be -1 at all points where x is not a multiple of `b`.

Since you are trying to maximize `Y`, you can use this information.  You can't use simple maximization functions across a multiple of `b` boundary, but on any domain `[nb, (n+1)b)`, the function is continuous and differentiable.  You can derive an equation for the local maximum value of `Y` on any given segment.  Once you have this, you can approach the problem in discrete space.  Given a bunch of segments, each with its own local maximum, what is the global maximum.

Of course, the answer to this particular problem is that there is no maximum for `Y`.  You'll find the range for `Y` is `[0, b)`, which is a range that has no maximum.  You can asymptotically approach `b`, but you'll never reach that value.

Comment: I edited my expression please have a look at it .

Comment: You can apply the same logic

Comment: please look at it the question has been edited

Comment: Think of it like a homework exercise.  I've given you almost the entire answer.  All you have to do is take it one more step.